# How to manage code to display animation only once?

Tags: c++, opengl, animation

i am making a program to animate a ball over a field
it goes like,

```
void display()
{
/*
code to draw a field

*/
loop:1 to 5
loop:1 to 6
/*
here comes the code to animate the ball over the field

*/
}
```

I want whenever user press "right_Arrow" the whole scene get rotated by
some angle
problem:whenever the user presses "right_Arrow" key it rotate the scene by  some angle   but also display whole animation again...but i want animation to be displayed only once(after maximazing window) and then the user can rotate the whole scene
by some angle without displaying any animation on pressing "right_Arrow" key
How should i do this in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again your problem lies in your mistake to do the animation completely in the display function. I extended my example I wrote you yesterday a bit; After starting the program, the animation will play for 5 seconds, then stop. Pressing [R] resets the animation (thus starts it again), pressing [+] / [-] rotates the scene around the Y axis.

http://homepages.physik.uni-muenchen.de/~Wolfgang.Draxinger/stuff/sinsphere_rot.c
*EDIT: commenting*

```
/* This is ANSI-C - don't try to compile with a C++ compiler, it will fail! */
#include <GL/glut.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#include <sys/time.h>
#include <math.h>

#define M_PI    3.1415926535897932384626433832795029L
#define M_PI_2  1.5707963267948966192313216916397514L

# define timersub(a, b, result)                                               \
  do {                                                                        \
    (result)->tv_sec = (a)->tv_sec - (b)->tv_sec;                             \
    (result)->tv_usec = (a)->tv_usec - (b)->tv_usec;                          \
    if ((result)->tv_usec < 0) {                                              \
      --(result)->tv_sec;                                                     \
      (result)->tv_usec += 1000000;                                           \
    }                                                                         \
  } while (0)

void idle(void);
void animate(float dT);
void display(void);
void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y);
void init_sphere(unsigned int rings, unsigned int sectors);
void draw_sphere(void);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE);
    glutCreateWindow("SinSphere");
    glutIdleFunc(idle);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
    glutDisplayFunc(display);

    init_sphere(10, 30);

    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

This is all just boilerplate code, nothing special.

```
struct AnimationState
{
    float time;
    float duration;
    float sphere_speed;
    float sphere_path_radius;
    float sphere_path_bobbing;
    float sphere_position[3];
};

static struct AnimationState animation = {
    0.,
    5., /* play for 5 seconds */
    0.1, 3., 1.,
    {1., 0., 0.}
};
```

AnimationState got an additional element `duration`; after that time the animation will stop playing, by testing if `animation.time < animation.duration` and only advance the animation step if so.

```
void animate(float dT)
{
    if(animation.time < animation.duration) {
        animation.time += dT;

        animation.sphere_position[0] = animation.sphere_path_radius * cos(2*M_PI * animation.time * animation.sphere_speed);
        animation.sphere_position[1] = animation.sphere_path_bobbing * sin(2*M_PI * animation.time * 5 * animation.sphere_speed);
        animation.sphere_position[2] = animation.sphere_path_radius * sin(2*M_PI * animation.time * animation.sphere_speed);
    }
}

struct ViewState {
    float rotation;
    float rotation_step;
};

static struct ViewState view = {
    0.,
    0.1
};
```

ViewState stores the rotation. This is really a dumbed down version, usually implements this through a view transformation matix and steppings for that.

```
void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    switch(key) {
    case 'R':
    case 'r': /* restart animation */
        animation.time = 0.;
        break;

    case '+':
        view.rotation += view.rotation_step;
        break;

    case '-':
        view.rotation -= view.rotation_step;
        break;
    }
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

Keyboard handler function should be obvious.

```
GLfloat *sphere_vertices_normals;
unsigned int sphere_quads = 0;
GLushort *sphere_indices;

void init_sphere(unsigned int rings, unsigned int sectors)
{
    float const R = 1./(float)(rings-1);
    float const S = 1./(float)(sectors-1);
    int r, s;

    sphere_vertices_normals = malloc(sizeof(GLfloat)*3 * rings*sectors);

    GLfloat *v = sphere_vertices_normals;
    for(r = 0; r < rings; r++) for(s = 0; s < sectors; s++) {
        float const y = sin( -M_PI_2 + M_PI * r * R );

        float const x = cos(2*M_PI * s * S) * sin( M_PI * r * R );

        float const z = sin(2*M_PI * s * S) * sin( M_PI * r * R );

        v[0] = x;
        v[1] = y;
        v[2] = z;

        v+=3;
    }

    sphere_indices = malloc(sizeof(GLushort) *  rings * sectors * 4);
    GLushort *i = sphere_indices;
    for(r = 0; r < rings; r++) for(s = 0; s < sectors; s++) {
        *i++ = r * sectors + s;
        *i++ = r * sectors + (s+1);
        *i++ = (r+1) * sectors + (s+1);
        *i++ = (r+1) * sectors + s; 
        sphere_quads++;
    }
}
```

`init_sphere` build us some nice vertex and index array containing sphere geometry. Exercise for the reader: Put it in a Vertex Buffer Object.

```
void draw_sphere()
{
    glTranslatef(animation.sphere_position[0], animation.sphere_position[1], animation.sphere_position[2]);

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);

    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, sphere_vertices_normals);
    glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, sphere_vertices_normals);
    glDrawElements(GL_QUADS, sphere_quads*4, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, sphere_indices);
}

void idle()
{
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

The idle function gets called after all input events have been processed. Input events are keypresses and the like. GLUT events only get processed after the display handler returns. So you must not implement the animation timer loop within the display handler. Instead you determine the time for a single display, then advance the loop by that timestep for the next display iteration. `idle` initiate the next display pass after event processing.

```
static GLfloat const light_pos[4] = {-1., 1., 1., 0.};
static GLfloat const light_color[4] = {1., 1., 1., 1.};

void display()
{
    static struct timeval delta_T = {0., 0.};
    struct timeval time_frame_begin, time_frame_end;

    int win_width, win_height;
    float win_aspect;

    gettimeofday(&time_frame_begin, 0);

    animate(delta_T.tv_sec + delta_T.tv_usec * 1.e-6);

    win_width = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH);
    win_height = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT);
    win_aspect = (float)win_width/(float)win_height;

    glViewport(0, 0, win_width, win_height);
    glClearColor(0.6, 0.6, 1.0, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glFrustum(-win_aspect, win_aspect, -1., 1., 1., 10.);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(0,0,-5.5);

    glRotatef(view.rotation * 180./M_PI, 0, 1, 0);

    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, light_pos);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, light_color);

    glPushMatrix();

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    draw_sphere();

    glPopMatrix();

    glutSwapBuffers();

    gettimeofday(&time_frame_end, 0);
    timersub(&time_frame_end, &time_frame_begin, &delta_T);

}
```

Instead of measureing the time spent in `display` a more accurate approach is measuring the time between each invocation of `display` to take time spent in other parts of the programm into account. This is an exercise left to the reader.

Comment: would you mind if you can modify my code to implement he desired functionality since i am getting so many errors while running your program on vs2008

Comment: @fluty: The program is valid ANSI-C. It's not C++, so if you pasted that code into a VS2008 C++ project it's the explanation for the errors. Also I'd require the full source code for the changes. But it's not so much important that you actually **compile and run** *my* program. Instead you should **read and understand** what the code does and apply what you've learnt on *your* program.

Comment: here is my code..please make the required changes i am realy stuck

Hawk.c
http://pastebin.com/gEYi9Vsj

GluCylinders.h
http://pastebin.com/SeYkSTHd

Comment: @fluty: You code is one big mess. I tried to fix as much as I could: http://pastebin.com/eWDtdgvm But honestly: I'd burn it down and rewrite from scratch.

Comment: Your name will be written with golden characters in the history of stackoverflow for pointing others to heap of your knowledge, i wish i wld upvote you by million times